# Shopify Node Server command don't working

Tags: shopify

I need to develop an app with node/react and embed it into Shopify. I installed Shopify CLI properly. From installed CLI I created a new app. When I type `shopify node server` command on the terminal, I get this error message.

> tar is required for installing ngrok. Please install tar using the
> appropriate package manager for your system.

Is there any program that is named `tar`? Or what does `tar` refers to for this case? How I can overcome this problem. I am in trouble. my operating system is windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to manually install ngrok in your system and then run command
make sure its `shopify node serve` not `shopify node server`

Comment: thanks for correction, i've made what you said but still it's not working.

Comment: after downloading put ngrok.exe file in AppData/local/shopify folder

Answer (score 3):

they changed the cmd to `shopify app serve`

for shopify-cli version: 2.7

Answer (score 0):

On windows, try to use cmd as admin, that works for me c: then you can use the command in any term

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).